# HttpValueCollection and NameValueCollection

Tags: c#

What is the difference between `HttpValueCollection` and `NameValueCollection`? 
If possible please explain with example.

Thanks

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`NameValueCollection` is case sensitive for the keys, `HttpValueCollection` isn't. Also `HttpValueCollection` is an internal class that derives from `NameValueCollection` that you are never supposed to use directly in your code. Another property of `HttpValueCollection` is that it automatically url encodes values when you add them to this collection.

Here's how to use the `HttpValueCollection` class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // returns an implementation of NameValueCollection
        // which in fact is HttpValueCollection
        var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        values["param1"] = "v&=+alue1";
        values["param2"] = "value2";*

        // prints "param1=v%26%3d%2balue1&param2=value2"
        Console.WriteLine(values.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Also at what situation we should use HttpValueCollection and NameValueCollection?

Comment: @Amit, when you deal with urls and want to generate properly encoded parameters you could use `HttpValueCollection`. `NameValueCollection` due to its non-generic nature is not a class that I would use. I would prefer a more strongly typed `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` for example.

Comment: Small correction - NameValueCollection is **case insensitive** for the keys by default, unless case sensitive comparer is specified in constructor.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, Dictionary has a few differences from NameValueCollection: it doesn't maintain insertion order, and it only allows one value per key. They often can be used in the same way, but if you have values that will end up in a query string, you may end up needing to switch. Just something I've run in to.

Comment: "never supposed to use for your code" Of course they're deprive us of a useful feature. -_-

Answer (score 10):

One point that is not obvious in Darin's answer is that `NameValueCollection` does not override `ToString()` method, while `HttpValueCollection` overrides it. This particular property and implicit URL encoding of values makes the latter one a right choice if you want to convert the collection back to query string.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var httpValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        httpValueCollection["param1"] = "value1";
        httpValueCollection["param2"] = "value2";
        Console.WriteLine(httpValueCollection.ToString());

        var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
        nameValueCollection["param1"] = "value1";
        nameValueCollection["param2"] = "value2";
        Console.WriteLine(nameValueCollection.ToString());  
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
param1=value1&param2=value2
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
```