# How can I consume the api with the body and type x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: c#, api

I need to add a key with its respective body value of type x-www-form-urlencoded to get the token, but I don't know how to do it, I'm new consuming the rest in C #, help would be appreciated.

[image: Postman]

```
            HttpWebRequest requestObj = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://url/token");
            requestObj.Method = "POST";
            requestObj.PreAuthenticate = true;
            requestObj.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "dato";
            requestObj.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


            HttpWebResponse responseObj = null;
            responseObj = (HttpWebResponse)requestObj.GetResponse();
            string strresult = null;
            using (Stream stream = responseObj.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                strresult = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.WriteLine("Resultado correcto: " + strresult);
                sr.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post form data using HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702902/post-form-data-using-httpwebrequest)

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try with this code, it may help to you to resolve your issue,

```
      HttpWebRequest requestObj = 
        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://url/token");
        requestObj.Method = "POST";
        requestObj.PreAuthenticate = true;
        requestObj.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "dato";
        requestObj.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        using (var stream = requestObj.GetRequestStream())           
        {
          //Handle the data for request
          //stream.Write();
        }                       

       if(requestObj.HaveResponse){
          HttpWebResponse responseObj = null; 
          responseObj = (HttpWebResponse)requestObj.GetResponse();
          var strresult = new StreamReader(responseObj .GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
       }
```