# How to send POST with form data in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program that requests my website with a username, password, hardware ID and a key in POST.

I have this code here that should send a POST request to my website with that form data, but when it sends, my webserver reports back that it didn't receive the POST data

```cs
try
{
    string poststring = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}&key={2}&hwid={3}", Username, Password, "272453745345934756392485764589", GetHardwareID());
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest =
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("mywebsite");

    httpRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(poststring);
    httpRequest.ContentLength = bytedata.Length;

    Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
    requestStream.Close();


    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse =
    (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    using (StreamReader reader =
    new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.Append(line);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
catch (Exception Error)
{
    return Error.ToString();
}
```

If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post form data using HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702902/post-form-data-using-httpwebrequest)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per [`HttpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8) documentation

> We don't recommend that you use `HttpWebRequest` for new development. Instead, use the [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) class.

`HttpClient` contains only asynchronous API because Web requests needs awaiting. That's not good to freeze entire Application while it's pending response.

Thus, here's some async function to make `POST` request with `HttpClient` and send there some data.

First of all, create `HttpClient` seperately [because](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#examples)

> `HttpClient` is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use.

```csharp
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

Then implement the method.

```csharp
private async Task<string> PostHTTPRequestAsync(string url, Dictionary<string, string> data)
{
    using (HttpContent formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data))
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, formContent).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Or C# 8.0

```csharp
private async Task<string> PostHTTPRequestAsync(string url, Dictionary<string, string> data)
{
    using HttpContent formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, formContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Looks easier than your code, right?

Caller async method will look like

```
private async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> postData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    postData.Add("message", "Hello World!");
    try
    {
        string result = await PostHTTPRequestAsync("http://example.org", postData);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If you're not familiar with `async/await`, [it's time to say Hello](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: Long-lived HttpClients bring their own problems, and [there is now a recommended mechanism of instantiating HttpClients that mitigates those too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

Comment: @TomW but it's another long and interesting story. For educational purpose and small apps single instance of `HttpClient` is pretty good solution.