# Azure function POST request with attachments

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have a form with multiple fields and some attachments. I need to submit it to an Azure function using http trigger (Post).
Any guidance or sample how I can I write this Azure function using C#/.NET to accept fields data And Attachments?

Comment: Here's [something I've found](https://www.cyotek.com/blog/upload-data-to-blob-storage-with-azure-functions).

Comment: @aepot: this one is about creating a file from a body of the request. in my case it is submitting a form that has multiple fields (say: name, email, phone) PLUS some attached files

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62681494/12888024) then. To attach files you must encode it to Base64 and add as text to the params Dictionary.

Comment: @aepot Thanks, but what i am looking for is how to write the azure function to "accept" the fields and attachments. Not how to "send" the request

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the sample code below. I did some tests and it can receive parameters.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace AcceptFormData
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var formdata = await req.ReadFormAsync();
            string name = formdata["name"];
            string email = formdata["email"];
            string phone = formdata["phone"];
            var image = req.Form.Files["file"];
            
            log.LogInformation(name);
            log.LogInformation(email);
            log.LogInformation(phone);

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

The request body in postman is constructed like this：

[image]

I did it with reference to this [blog](https://blog.rasmustc.com/multipart-data-with-azure-functions-httptriggers/). I think this can solve your problem, if not, you can tell me.

Comment: Works fine. Was wondering if there is a better way to parse the formdata collection directly to a viewmodel object instead of reading and assigning properties one by one