# Unit test Request.QueryString.ToString()

Tags: c#, moq

I want to unit test a method that uses `Request.QueryString`, used like this:

```
 public void GetUrl(string url)
    {
        var queryString = this.context.Request.QueryString.ToString();

        var urlWithQueryString = url;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString))
        {
            urlWithQueryString = url + (url.Contains("?") ? "&" : "?") + queryString;
        }

        return urlWithQueryString;
    }
```

I try to stub the `QueryString` like this using Moq, with no suceess:

```
Mock<HttpRequestBase> Request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
Request.SetupGet(r => r.QueryString).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
```

Because the production code return name/value pairs, or empty string, while the unit test returns the full name of the class `NameValueCollection`.

Any idea?

Comment: can you post all unit test method code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why that happens is that at runtime, `Request.QueryString` is not exactly a `NameValueCollection`, but a `HttpValueCollection` - a derivative of `NameValueCollection` that overrides `ToString` to give you that nicely formatted result.

The `HttpValueCollection` class is private, so you cannot directly create an instance of it, but you can do this indirectly, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7514495/390819).

Concretely, instead of `new NameValueCollection()` you should use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("")`.

The resulting object implements the standard `NameValueCollection`, so you can for example call `Add(string name, string value)` after instantiating it.

Alternatively, you can pass a real querystring when creating it: `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("a=1&b=2")`