# Why does Request.QueryString.Get() and NameValueCollection.Get() return a decoded value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm observing some strange/unexepected behavior on a couple lines of code that pull values out of a query string.

function call

```
ValidateRequestNameValueCollection(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers // other params omitted
```

function definition

```
 private void ValidateRequestNameValueCollection(NameValueCollection nvc, // other params omitted
        {
            int count = nvc.Count;

            validationFailureIndex = 0;

            for (int index = 0; index < count; ++index)
            {
                string key = nvc.GetKey(index);

                if (null != key && key.StartsWith(DoubleUnderline, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    continue;

                string str = nvc.Get(index); // this is returning a decoded string
```

In visual studio debugger if I hover over the NameValueCollection parameter I see something similar to this:

{param=omitted3GCDqHrqg5w%2b6NJfc%3d}

this is clearly encoded, however when the `.get` is called, the string returned is decoded.  Based on the answer here: [HttpValueCollection and NameValueCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514461/httpvaluecollection-and-namevaluecollection) I think that the `NameValueCollection` parameter is silenty cast to a `HttpValueCollection` and that `HttpValueCollection` is automatically calling `UrlDecode` on get.  I couldn't find any documentation explicitly stating this though.  Does anyone know?

Comment: Why does it matter? You know that it does return a decoded value. The answer is "that's the way it's programmed". If you want to know why it was programmed that way, ask someone at Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpValueCollection.cs or https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/HttpValueCollection.cs

```
internal void FillFromString(String s, bool urlencoded, Encoding encoding) {
    ...
    if (urlencoded)
        base.Add(
            HttpUtility.UrlDecode(name, encoding),
            HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value, encoding));
    else
        ...
```

Comment: Just realizing that this doesn't help with how/why/when/if there is a silent cast to HttpValueCollection...i'll keep an eye out for that specifically.

Comment: Na this is perfect! Hopefully will help someone else in the future.