# UTF-8 URL Encode

Tags: c#, urlencode

I am having issues in encoding my query params using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` it is not getting converted to UTF-8.

```
 query["agent"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("{\"mbox\":\"mailto: UserName@company.com\"}");
```

I tried using the overload method and passed utf encoding but still it is not working.

expected result:

```
?agent=%7B%22mbox%22%3A%22mailto%3AUserName%40company.com%22%7D
```

Actual Result:

```
?agent=%257b%2522mbox%2522%253a%2522mailto%253aUserName%2540company.com%2522%257d

     public StatementService(HttpClient client, IConfiguration conf)
    {
        configuration = conf;
        var BaseAddress = "https://someurl.com/statements?";             
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Custom-Header", 
                                          "customheadervalue");
        Client = client;
    }

   public async Task<Object> GetStatements(){
     var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Client.BaseAddress.Query);
     query["agent"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode( "{\"mbox\":\"mailto:UserName@company.com\"}");

        var longuri = new Uri(Client.BaseAddress + query.ToString());
        
        var response = await Client.GetAsync(longuri);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        dynamic statement = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<object>(responseStream);
 //Convert stream reader to string 
        StreamReader JsonStream = new StreamReader(statement);
        string JsonString = JsonStream.ReadToEnd();
        //convert Json String to Object.
        JObject JsonLinq = JObject.Parse(JsonString);
        // Linq to Json
        dynamic res = JsonLinq["statements"][0].Select(res => res).FirstOrDefault();
        return await res;
```

}

Comment: 1) This has nothing to do with UTF-8, and 2) It looks like it's getting double-encoded: `{` is getting turned into `%7B`, and then the `%` is getting encoded to `%25`, turning it into `%257B`

Comment: Apparently something else is also doing encoding, so you can't change how encoding is done until you find and turn that other thing off, or accept that it's responsible for url encoding.

Comment: Have you tried `query["agent"] = "{\"mbox\":\"mailto: UserName@company.com\"}"`? Cause `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` returns something very similar to what you want.

Comment: I rather suspect that you don't need to call `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` at all, and that whatever you're passing `query` to is doing its own URL encoding. But without more details it's impossible to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` internally returns a `HttpValueCollection`. `HttpValueCollection.ToString()` already performs url encoding, so you don't need to do that yourself. If you do it yourself, it is performed twice and you get the wrong result that you see.

I don't see the relation to UTF-8. The value you use ({"mbox":"mailto: UserName@company.com"}) doesn't contain any characters that would look different in UTF-8.

References:

- [HttpValueCollection and NameValueCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514461/httpvaluecollection-and-namevaluecollection)
- [ParseQueryString source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/httpserverutility.cs,8c392029e2dd33f5,references)
- [HttpValueCollection source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/HttpValueCollection.cs)

Answer (score -2):

I strongly suggest you this other approach, using `Uri.EscapeDataString` method. This method is inside System.Net instead of System.Web that is a heavy dll. In addition `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` encode characters are in uppercase this would be an issue in certain cases while implementing HTTP protocols.

```
Uri.EscapeDataString("{\"mbox\":\"mailto: UserName@company.com\"}")
"%7B%22mbox%22%3A%22mailto%3A%20UserName%40company.com%22%7D"
```